# Why are jquery objects coming back undefined?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the value of my position attribute with jquery. For some reason when I try to get an element and display its position, it is coming back undefined. I've tried console.log a few different elements stored in variables as jquery objects, and they are coming back undefined. Seems like this is happening for all the elements I try to grab.

Pen: https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/QgXoMr

```js
// two functions, one changes to fixed 


var windw = this;

/*

//this one switches to fixed

$.fn.startFixed = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos + 200
            });
        }
    });
};

*/

// this one switches to absolute

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};


// playing with some values for switch positions


var asideHeight = $(".aside").height();
var stopPoint = asideHeight - 303;
var aside2Height = $("#aside2").height();
var secondStart = asideHeight + $(window).height();
var secondStop = 555;
var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();

$('.container-text').followTo(stopPoint);


/*

// trying to put jquery objects in variables but coming back undefined in console

var lastFixed = $("#lastFixed");
var fixedPos = lastFixed.position();

var secondFix = $("#section2");
var secondPos = secondFix.postition();

// undefined, why??

console.log(asideHeight);
console.log(aside2Height);
console.log(viewPortHeight);
console.log(stopPoint);
console.log(windw);
console.log(secondStart);
console.log(secondFix);  
console.log(secondPos);
*/
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;  
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}

section:nth-child(even) main {
  order: -1;
}

aside,main {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

aside{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
    justify-content: center;
  background: #eee;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

aside,.inner {
  padding: .5em;
}


.container-content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

article {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 75px;
}

.container-text{
    position: fixed;
}

#section2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000;
}
#section3 {
  position: absolute;
}
#lastFixed {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section>
      <aside class="aside">
        <div class="container-text">
          <header class="hello">Hello</header>
          <div class="container-nav">
            <p class="how">How</p>
            <p class="are">are</p>
            <p class="you">you</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main class="main">
          <div class="container-content">
              <h1>First heading</h1>
              <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
              </article>
              <h1>Second heading</h1>
              <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in Nulla facilisi. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi.
              </article>
              <h1>Third heading</h1>
              <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
              </article>
              <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
              <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
              </article>
            </div>
        </main>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two typo, it `position` not `postition` (74) or var `positon` (78)

Comment: Ugh, I need to pay more attention. Thanks for the timely reply anyway.